# Dropwizard setSessionHandler Error

Tags: maven, session, dropwizard

I am new to both Maven & Dropwizard. 
I am trying to build session management into my Dropwizard code. I followed the following guide: http://cosmo-opticon.net/blog/2013/1/23/session-based-security-in-dropwizard as recommended by another post.
When i added these lines to the run() method:
     `e.setSessionHandler(new org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler());`
     `e.scanPackagesForResourcesAndProviders(SessionUserProvider.class);`

where e = environment.

Eclipse is returning: The method setSessionHandler is undefined to the Type environment.
All the examples i have seen where environmeent.setSessionHandler where using dropwizard 0.6.0. I am using 0.7.0. Could the Environment class in 0.7.0 be missing these methods?

Here is my environment class:
    `import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;`

i am also importing session Handler:
    `import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler;`

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That method moved in 0.7.x. Try:

```java
e.getApplicationContext().setSessionHandler(new org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped a lot. AS for e.scanPackagesForResourcesAndProviders(SessionUserProvider.class);   i found an answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/eL01VgPkooI